# How to find and download a image file of specific resolution using wget?

Tags: command-line, wget

How can I find and download an image file of specific resolution e.g.: 100x99 whose file name is not known using `wget`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `wget` is a tool to download things off internet. It's not meant to have search capabilities. You need to know the URI of the file you want to download.

Comment: You need to know the exact URL or download the whole page with wget and then extract the image with grep/sed/awk/python/something and then wget that image.

Comment: does it have to be wget or can it be a python script?

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to [Google Images](https://www.google.com/imghp) with  a browser like Firefox.
2. Add a search term and click on search options.
3. Select exact resolution and enter your numbers.
4. Select an appropriate image.
5. Click on the image and copy the URL.
6. Open a terminal and enter `wget COPIED_URL`.

For instance the [search for term »ubuntu«](https://www.google.com/search?q=ubuntu&site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=lnt&tbs=isz:ex,iszw:100,iszh:99) leads to this URL: `http://virtualization.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/03/virtualization-kvm-ubuntu.png`
and this image: [image]